# I have problem with GetConnectionString in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a problem connecting a database using ASP.NET MVC and the identification system. I want to connect to mySQL.

First, I launched xampp, next definition connection string. And then in the Configure Services method, I used UseMySQL instead of the default connection.

If I enter the default connection in various forms, I have throw error that the string cannot be converted to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Serverversion`.

I found a similar problem and wrote `MySqlServerVersion`, but it doesn't work. `GetConnectionString` doesn't take 2 arguments.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIH2s.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFlPI.png

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? And sorry for my English.

Comment: Please add code as _text_ not _images_!

Comment: Could you pls share which package do you use for `UseMySql` extension? Besides which is your real target framework, asp.net core or asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

`UseMySql` takes 2 arguments, the `ConnectionString` and the `Version` (optional). You're trying to set the version when you get the connection string, simply move your parentheses up a level:

`options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 11))`